# Regexp_like from text

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm always in trouble with regular expressions:

So i made a query with `listagg`:

Output:

```
21.09.2017 09:43  Status 8-2#Partner 0-178#EXP_date 24-2#EXP_interval 30-365#Partner_code template-0925584#amount 0-70#

21.11.2019 08:10  Status 8-2#Partner 0-178#EXP_date 24-0#EXP_interval 30-1#Partner_code template-0925805#

17.12.2019 10:23  Status 5-1#
```

I need to regexp this "text" with values `Status`,`1#`,`2#`

```
regexp_like(my_column,'Status (1#|2#)')
```

So i want all of the rows, where exists `Status` **AND** `('1#'` **OR** `'2#')` at same time.

What is the correct form of `regexp_like` ?

Comment: You probably don't need regular expressions at all, just a `having` clause.  If you want to fix your query, then ask a *new* question -- this has already been answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff might be, but the "output" is from 3 cols: timestamp||' '||user(not listed here)||' '||modifications. The modifications col contains the whole text (Status, etc..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shorten the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with the `|` to a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Match the space after Status and then use `.*` to get to matching either 1# or 2#

```
Status .*[12]#
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZ4s20/1)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
regexp_like(my_column,'Status .*(1|2)#')
```

The problem with your original regex is that it was expecting `'1#'` or `'2#'` right after `'Status '`. Adding `'.*'` allows any sequence of characters in between.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to capture until the first #** then use `.+?` else use `.*` for last `#`

```
Status.+?(1|2)#
```

**REGEX DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/15pvJz/5

**Explanation:**

> `.+?` matches any character (**except for line terminators**)
>
> `+?` Quantifier — Matches between **one** and **unlimited** times, as few
> times as possible, expanding as needed (**lazy**)